# access to <url> forbidden; SVN with Apache and LDAP

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ldap, svn

I'm setting up an SVN server on a CentOS VM. What I want to achieve is an SVN server on port 443 with multiple repositories accessible at an address `https://192.168.0.5:443/svn/ReposXX/trunk`, for example. The network works fine. The new server is static on `192.168.0.5`. I'm trying to checkout a repository as a first test and I can't seem to get it working. I always get 'forbidden' (more details below!).

```
[root@svn svn]# uname -a
Linux svn 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@svn svn]# ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.46.72) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from ord08s11-in-f8.1e100.net (173.194.46.72): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=31.6 ms
```

The svn repositories are in `/var/www/svn/svn/`. All folders/repositories inside belong to `apache.apache` and have `664` rights.

```
[root@svn svn]# pwd
/var/www/svn/svn
[root@svn svn]# ls -la
total 68
drw-rw-r--. 17 apache apache 4096 Nov 28 19:05 .
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root   root   4096 Nov 29 16:20 ..
drw-rw-r--.  7 apache apache 4096 Nov 28 18:38 Repos01
drw-rw-r--.  7 apache apache 4096 Nov 28 18:29 Repos02
drw-rw-r--.  7 apache apache 4096 Nov 28 18:47 Repos03
... 15 in total
```

I've been following various howtos and tutorials all over the place, and they're all making things in slightly different ways and none seem to be complete.

```
me@My-PC:~/SVN_TEST$ svn co https://192.168.0.5:443/random/Repos01/trunk/ Repos01
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://192.168.0.5:443/random/Repos01/trunk': 200 OK (https://192.168.100.5)
me@My-PC:~/SVN_TEST$ svn co https://192.168.0.5:443/svn/Repos01/trunk/ Repos01
svn: access to 'https://192.168.0.5:443/svn/Repos01/trunk' forbidden
```

The fact that I get `200 OK` (wrong URL) when I use a wrong URL, and `forbidden` when I use a good one tells me that I at least have a part of it working.

So here are the configurations so far...

In `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` I updated the line `ServerName 192.168.0.5:443`. I removed any `Listen` statement, as there's a `Listen 443` line in `ssl.conf`.

Here's the content of `/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf`:

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module     modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module   modules/mod_authz_svn.so
# SSL certificate location
#SSLEnable
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/private.pem
<Location /svn>
   DAV svn
   SVNParentPath /var/www/svn/svn

   # Limit write permission to list of valid users.
   <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
      # Require SSL connection for password protection.
      SSLRequireSSL

      AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/svn_access_file
      AuthType Basic
      AuthName "Subversion repos"
      AuthBasicProvider ldap
      AuthLDAPURL ldap://192.168.0.3:389/OU=CORP,DC=domCORP,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
      AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
      AuthLDAPBindDN "me@domCORP.local"
      AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypass"
#      Require ldap-group Users
#      AuthUserFile /etc/svn_auth_file
      AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN off
      Require valid-user
   </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

I tested the LDAP parameters with `ldapsearch` and it seems to work fine. I want to LDAP to be responsible for authentication, and `svn_access_file` to be responsible for access management (that's why I commented out `svn_auth_file`).

I added a rule to the firewall to have 443 going through.

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

Above the first `REJECT` rule.

The server's only purpose will be to serve SVN repository, so it was a fresh install before, and there will not be anything else added.

I generated the certificates following a howto online...

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out private.key 2048
openssl rsa -in -key private.key -out private.pem
openssl req -new -key private.key -out request.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 1000 -in request.csr -signKey private.key -out public.key
cp public.crt /etc/pki/tls/certs/public.crt
cp private.key /etc/pki/tls/private/private.key
cp private.pem /etc/pki/tls/private/private.pem
```

I'm sorry if I give too much, or unrelated information... Trying to show that I tried to make it work quite a bit.

I also tried to checkout from a Windows machine with TortoiseSVN. It asked me to accept the certificate, then refused with `Access to 'https://192.168.0.5/svn/Repos01/trunk' forbidden`.

So, on Linux and Windows, it doesn't ask for any login//password and just tells me that it's forbidden.

Any help on this is *greatly* appreciated.

**2013-11-30 Developments since yesterday**

I gave more attention to the logs and could make things slightly progress. Looking at `/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log`, I fixed

```
Can't open file '/etc/svn_access_file': Permission denied.
```

Which led to

```
Can't open file '/var/www/svn/svn/ReposXX/format': Permission denied
```

I thought SELinux might be in the way, so I did

```
chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/svn
```

But that didn't help. I then deactivated SELinux completely to make sure it wasn't possibly part of the problem anymore.

I tried to change the rights to `www` or `www-data`, but these user don't even exist... so I didn't bother and left `apache.apache`.

I also found somewhere these lines to set the file and directory rights:

```
find /var/www/svn/ -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
find /var/www/svn/ -type d -exec chmod 2770 {} \;
```

Didn't help either. That's where I'm at. I still get the error on `format` file in `ssl_error_log`.

Comment: Could you try to move your svn base dir outside of /var/www to see if it makes a difference? It may overlap with already defined DocumentRoot, /var/svn (or else where).

Comment: What entries are added to the Apache error log when these requests come in?

Comment: You said this is a new installation. Do you have SELinux still enforcing? Can you access the URL from the local machine?

Comment: `chmod -R 755(or 644) /var/www/svn/svn/` and try again. I suspect your sub directories may have different permissions or you haven't set the `AuthzSVNAccessFile` file correct. Could you post an example of it?

Comment: I first tried to add context using the command in today's update in main post... That didn't help, so I disabled SELinux altogether to make sure it wasn't part of the problem. Rebooted and that didn't help.

Comment: @tftd: I'm not too sure what to use as rights... I tried 666, 664, 660/2770 according to recommendations I could find everywhere. I just tried 644 and 755 as you suggested and it didn't change the permission error on `format`. About the access file, I took the one I used on the now defunct server. It should be well formed and working. You just made me think of clearing the login data in TortoiseSVN which didn't help. It doesn't ask for login info at all. It makes me accept the certificate, then that's it... using `tail -f` I see the `format` file error appear once more.

Comment: I tried to `svn co https://localhost:443/ReposXX/trunk ReposXX` in the home folder on the server iteself. It made me accept the certificate and said `Could not open the requested SVN filesystem`. Same error on `format` in the logs.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: Thanks, I've given a lot more attention to the logs since I saw your comment. Made me realize I had a small configuration problem: it looked in `/var/www/svn/svn/svn` (3 `svn` instead of 2).

Comment: @erny: I did `cp -R /var/www/svn/svn /srv` and readjusted rights and ownerships. I changed the `SVNParentPath` for `/srv/svn` and guess what... It worked!! You were right! If you copy your comment in a post below, you get the checkmark! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @M.Joanis: I wrote a complete answer, as you suggested. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html) states:

> Be sure that when you define your new Location, it doesn't overlap
>   with other exported locations. For example, if your main DocumentRoot
>   is exported to /www, do not export a Subversion repository in
>   . If a request comes in for the URI
>   /www/repos/foo.c, Apache won't know whether to look for a file
>   repos/foo.c in the DocumentRoot, or whether to delegate mod_dav_svn to
>   return foo.c from the Subversion repository. The result is often an
>   error from the server of the form 301 Moved Permanently.

It is recommended installing repos outside of /var/www as the Apache default configuration already defines permissions on that DocumentRoot which could overlap with the svn configurations.

Perhaps it's a good idea if you try to move your repos directories outside of /var/www and reconfigure Apache in accordance.